# How to get the distribution of all the times in a queue?

Tags: queue, simulation, distribution, anylogic, agent

Edit: The solution was that the serviceRate was too high for the amount of arriving trucks.

In my Anylogic model, I have a population of terminals (5) and a population of trucks (100). The trucks visit the terminals, which are a queueing model for them. The terminals have a number of gates (e.g., 7) that can all service 1 truck at a time (service time is based on a uniform distribution). If all the gates are busy, the other trucks have to wait in a (FIFO) queue in front of the terminal.

I want to measure **the time trucks are standing within the queues** before the terminals (without the service time). How can I create these terminal processes best within my Anylogic model?

I tried using a service block (the first processes in the picture), but I think that gives all the time and not only the time within the queue. I also tried a queue and delay block (below), to be able to measure the queue time. However, the distribution of the time measurement is not working as I get no distribution but just 1 (very small) number, as can be seen in the lowest picture. Same if I measure the time within the service or delay block... Does any body know how to let this work? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You delay capacity is `numberOfGates`. It means if that value is 5, then 5 trucks will move into delay block at the same time. Other arrived trucks will wait in the queue if `delay.size()=5`. There is nothing wrong in this, you should check if your model really works as intended.

The agents would move into delay block immediately if you selected the `maximum capacity` option in the delay block.

Also instead of timeMeasureStart/End, use your own assignments. That is, inside the delay, on enter type `agent.waitStart = time();` and upon leaving type `yourHistogramData.add(time()-agent.waitStart);`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited my question to better explain how I want the terminal and queue to work. If all gates are occupied, I want the trucks to wait in the queue (and measure only the time they are in this queue, without the service/delay time). Am I using the capacity correct as the number of servers? I tried the histogram data like you explained, but still got the same problem (1 number). Same when I measured it within the Queue block...

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that the service rate was too high for the amount of trucks I send to the terminal.

Comment: Instead of self-answering such not-reproducible questions, please delete the thread altogether - it is highly unlikely that it will be useful for anyone else in the future (which is actually the sole purpose of SO).

Comment: I tried to delete it but it is not possible because people answered on it.

Comment: I think you can always delete your questions as long as they do not have *upvoted* answers.

Comment: I have tried several times but it is not possible. It gives me this answer: _You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center._